# Update Row, Inner Join With Getting Top Row

Tags: sql, mariadb

Using MariaDB

I am trying to update the `membershipRenewDate`(In `officiantsDetails` Table) using the MAX value from `renewDate`(in `officiantsRenewals` Table)

Inner Join on `officiant_id` (same column name for both tables)

I have something like this but am getting syntax error.

```
UPDATE officiantsDetails offd 
SET offd.membershipRenewDate = offr.renewDate
FROM (SELECT TOP (1) renewDate, officiant_id FROM officiantsRenewals ORDER BY renewDate DESC ) as offr
WHERE offd.officiant_id = offr.officiant_id
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Do you have anything in your error log?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (SELECT TOP (1) renewDate, officiant_id FROM officiantsRenewals ORDER BY re' at line 15

Comment: Line 15 is the 'FROM' statement

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: It could be your database... some don't let you use `FROM` in `UPDATE` ... mariadb isn't it? Hmm... not sure if MariaDB does or doesn't

Comment: See also `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a Common Table Expression (CTE) for this. You use the `WITH` clause to define your "subquery", and then `INNER JOIN` the CTE to the table you want to update. It would look something like this:

```
WITH Top1RenewDate AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (1) 
        renewDate, 
        officiant_id 
    FROM officiantsRenewals 
    ORDER BY renewDate DESC 
)
UPDATE offd
SET offd.membershipRenewDate = offr.renewDate
FROM officiantsDetails offd
INNER JOIN Top1RenewDate offr ON offd.officiants_id = offr.officiants_id
```

This same syntax will also work for SQL Server, although you'd need to add a `;` before the `WITH` keyword on that system.

Comment: ^^ Nice, somehow, I've never heard of CTE myself, going to look into it now!

Comment: I get the answer, but not the upvote.  This has nothing to do with MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is not MariaDB.  In MariaDB, you can use a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE officiantsDetails offd JOIN
       (SELECT renewDate, officiant_id
        FROM officiantsRenewals
        ORDER BY renewDate DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) offr
       ON offd.officiant_id = offr.officiant_id
    SET offd.membershipRenewDate = offr.renewDate;
```

The syntax you are using is more reminiscent of SQL Server.